# Random numbers- only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, polar-coordinates

```
from math import sin, cos, pi
import numpy as np
N=10

a=np.random.randint(0, 360+1, N)
print (a)

theta=a*pi/180
print(theta)

x=[cos(theta)]
print(x)
y=[sin(theta)]
print(y)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-632b45c2aba1> in <module>()
      9 theta=a*pi/180
     10 print(theta)
---> 11 x=[cos(theta)]
     12 print(x)
     13 y=[sin(theta)]

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Please format your code with a code block

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `np.cos(theta)` instead of `cos(theta)`. Same goes for `sin`.

Only NumPy functions can be applied both to scalars and arrays. The regular `cos()` and `sin()` instead expect only scalar arguments, and fail in the example, as you try to apply them on a NumPy array of size 10.

NumPy `cos` documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html
`cos` documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html